# what's difference about git branch -d <branchname> and git branch -D <branchname>

Tags: git

I an newer about git. after I merge my branch from another branch, I found something wrong. Now my status is I have commit these changes from merging, but not push into the origin/mybranch. So I just wanna delete my local branch. Then I use git branch -d mybranch. However, it failed. It told me that I cann't delete my local branch. After searching goolge, I found the command git branch -D mybranch, and used it to delete my branch successfully. So could anyone told the difference about these two commands ?

Comment: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch

Comment: Also excellent documentation: https://www.kernel.org/pub//software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-D` is a force-delete and the `-d` will provide a warning before deleting if the branch has not been merged into its upstream branch

Comment: I am confused with what's the meaning of upstream branch. Can you give me a link about what's the upstream branch? Thank you! @Joe Philllips

Comment: The upstream branch is the branch you pull your changes from. you can use `git branch -vv` to find out what it is. (usually a branch called master tracks a remote branch origin/master.)

Comment: The remote branch is usually the upstream branch. origin/master would be the upstream branch of your local master branch

Answer (score 4):

You can find the answer using `git help branch`. (Because it is regarding the `git branch` command.)

There you find:

```
-d
--delete

    Delete a branch. The branch must be fully merged in its upstream branch, or in HEAD if no upstream was set with --track or --set-upstream.
-D

    Delete a branch irrespective of its merged status.
```

Usually you do `git branch -d`. - If git complains, you should think again and if you are sure you do not need any commits from that branch anymore you can do `git branch -D` to delete it anyway.